# Can't create alerts for document Library for which users can only read their own documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert

I am having a document Library in SPO. When I click on the list alerts I am getting an error:

[image]

Nothing is said in this message.

I am having "Designer" permissions with the right "Manage alerts" enabled, can any one help on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It’s the default behavior that user cannot create alert when we set read access on their own items.

As a workaround, you can create a custom workflow to use “send email” action and start workflow automatically when the item changed in SharePoint Designer.

Here is a similar [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10/cannot-create-alerts-for-lists-for-which-users-can/626ffcd9-ff3b-48a7-858b-02979335b6a7) for your reference.

Comment: SP_Admin (or users with Full Control - could be a site adminsitrator) can also set up alerts for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add to Hellofiona's answer by explaining something which she alludes to.  If you check in the List Settings>Advanced Settings.

Hellofiona suggests that you need to check that 'Read access' is set to **Read all items** and not 'Read items that were created by the user'.

[image: Advanced Settings screen shot]

Comment: Yes I have checked this.
But I cant found this option in my Advances Setting : https://ibb.co/jG8i0S
Where is this option ?

Comment: I looked at your screen shot, I realise now that you are working with a Document Library (Excel, Word etc) and not with a List.  The Advanced Settings menu is different.  My answer and Fiona's answer are based on Lists rather than Document Libraries.  Unfortunately I don't know how to help with your question.

Comment: For your information, [here is a guide to setting up alerts on document libraries](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-alerts/) - this shows how it should work.

Comment: Ye, thats not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly there is no option to create alert for read items who created by